# mrjob add_file_arg() csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, mrjob

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the add_file_arg() for mrjob. I'm trying to pass a csv to my mapper with a person's attributes and find the attributes for each person in my mapper. This is my code thus far:

```
class MRPeopleScores(MRJob):
    def configure_args(self):
        super(MRPeopleScores, self).configure_args()
        self.add_file_arg('--database')

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        print(self.options.database)
```

When I run

```
python3 calculate_people_scores.py --jobconf mapreduce.job.reduces=1 data/people_ids.csv database=data/people_attributes.csv
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "calculate_people_scores.py", line 88, in <module>
MRPeopleScores.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 439, in run
mr_job.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 460, in execute
super(MRJob, self).execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 161, in execute
self.run_job()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 231, in run_job
runner.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 476, in run
self._run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 185, in _run
self._invoke_step(step_num, 'mapper')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 272, in _invoke_step
working_dir, env)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mrjob/inline.py", line 154, in _run_step
child_instance.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 448, in execute
self.run_mapper(self.options.step_num)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 526, in run_mapper
for out_key, out_value in mapper(key, value) or ():
File "calculate_people_scores.py", line 47, in mapper
print(self.options.database)
AttributeError: 'Values' object has no attribute 'database'
```

I'm sure I'm grossly misunderstanding how to use this argument, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your error is in this line: `print(self.options.database)`. Note `self.options` is a `Values` object.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear what a Values object is. How would I go about reading the csv file in my mapper?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run  `--database data/people_attributes.csv` instead of `database=data/people_attributes.csv` first.

```
python3 calculate_people_scores.py --jobconf mapreduce.job.reduces=1 data/people_ids.csv --database data/people_attributes.csv
```

with passing `--database` you just pass path of the file, so you need to open it first, before doing anything with it. you can do this by overriding `reducer_init()` or `mapper_init()` functions this way:

```
def mapper_init(self):
    self.db=open(self.options.database)
```

or

```
def reducer_init(self):
    self.db=open(self.options.database)
```

now you can work with `self.db` in your mapper or reducer.
it's not recommended to `print` mapper or reducer output, you should use `yield` instead.
in other hands it's not suggested to print(or yield) your second file(`self.db`) in mapper or reducer, cause it will run as many as number of mappers or reducers. but you can do it this way:

```
def mapper(self, _, line):
     print(self.db.readlines())
     # OR
     yield(None,self.db.readlines())
```

at the end you can access your csv content like this:

```
def mapper(self,_,line):
        for li in self.db:
            fields=li.split(',')
            yield(fields[0],fields[1])
```